# Any other services like MouseTrace? How useful is it?

Tags: analytics

I just need to know if there are any alternatives to mousetrace - http://www.mousetrace.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Clicktale,](http://www.clicktale.com/product/mouse_move_heatmaps) [Mouseflow,](http://mouseflow.com/) [Clickdensity,](http://www.clickdensity.com/) [Foresee,](http://www.foreseeresults.com/products/session-replay.shtml) [CrazyEgg,](http://www.crazyegg.com/) and [Silverback](http://silverbackapp.com/) (Mac app) all offer heatmap and/or cursor tracking.

**Heat maps** of the sort that CrazyEgg provide tend to be more useful than cursor tracking, particularly when split testing two alternative designs, because they provide an at-a-glance comparison of a design's effectiveness.

**Cursor tracking** requires you watch video playback, so it's much more time consuming to collect useful data like this. It can be great for testing web apps and software interfaces among small sample groups of about 10 people, though. Any more than that and you tend to waste time watching footage to see the same results repeated over.

In general, goal-based metrics are more useful than pretty pictures and fancy mouse capturing. [Google Analytics Goals](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55515) allow you to define paths through a site and determine what percentage of your visitors follow that path to buy your product/sign up/download your stuff/subscribe to your blog/make an enquiry. Those are the important metrics worth setting up before you start playing with analytical eye candy.

Comment: wow! Thanks a lot for your detailed answer and useful insights. Helpful!